# Linq to Sql NotSupportedException "The explicit construction of the entity in a query is invalid" when selecting new Type of other Database Table

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to get a different data type from a Linq Query as the Result after grouping and averaging the Values from the grouped results together.

For example:

I have a Table called grades with these columns:

```
long StudentID
long ExamID
int Grade
```

And another Table called examAverage with a similar structure:

```
long ExamID
int Grade
```

Now i want to select all rows in the grades Table and group them by ExamID. Then average the grades and save the result for each Exam in the table examAverage.

The Query i have not looks like this

```
var values = (from grades in db.Grades
              group grades by grades.ExamID into avgGrade
              select new examAverage
                  {
                      ExamID = avgGrade.Key,
                      Grade= (int)avgGrade.Average(x => x.Grade)
                  });
```

unfortunately it always throws a System.NotSupportedException telling me that im not allowed to construct a new Instance of the Entitytype examAverage.
However when i swap the database for a List of grades and store the result in a List of the type examAverage it works just fine.

Now for my question.
Is it even possible to do something like that and how ? If not is there some other way of doing something similar to that ?

Comment: You should always PascalCase Class Names (so if you have a class named ExamAverage, it should start with a capital E.

What database are you connecting to? SQL server or something else? Are you using Linq to SQL, Entity Framework or nHibernate? I'm asking these questions because a "NotSupportedException" usually indicates your database driver doesn't support a particular operation. For example, it may not know how to translate "Average" to the specific dialect of SQL your database is using

Comment: @realbart I'm using a MS Sql Server (Express) and Linq to SQL

Comment: Does the NotSupportedException have a text? e.g. 'Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator' ?
If so, "Average" is not supported in groups.

Comment: When selecting a new anonymous type as the result .Average is supported.

Comment: The Excetion Message is: "The explicit construction of the entity " Example.examAverage " in a query is invalid."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that "examAverage" is also a Linq entity: it maps to a table or view.

Linq to Objects doesn't check for this, so that's why you don't get an exception when you query a list of objects. Linq to SQL DOES, partly because it wants to protect you from accedentally creating lots of entities containing data that containing data that does not reflect your actual database state.

So what you can do depends on what you want:

If you want to get a list of custom objects constructed in the database query, use a different type, e.g. MyExamAverage - possibly defined in another assembly.

If you actually want to create database records (select... into) you could use an anonymous type:

```
var values = (from grades in db.Grades
          group grades by grades.ExamID into avgGrade
          select new 
              {
                  ExamID = avgGrade.Key,
                  Grade= (int)avgGrade.Average(x => x.Grade)
              });

foreach (var value in values) 
{
    var grade = new examAverage{
       ExamID = value.ExamId,
       Grade = value.Grade
    };
    // save grade here
}
```

If you MUST return the list from a method, you could:

```
private IEnumerable<examAverage> GetGrades()
{

var values = (from grades in db.Grades
          group grades by grades.ExamID into avgGrade
          select new 
              {
                  ExamID = avgGrade.Key,
                  Grade= (int)avgGrade.Average(x => x.Grade)
              });
foreach (var value in values) yield return new examAverage{
       ExamID = value.ExamId,
       Grade = value.Grade
    };

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i hoped there would be another way other than using a forEach loop to convert in directly into the type of the other table but this will work als well :)

Comment: @LukasGoßmann if you change your question to contain "Linq to SQL", "SQL Sever", "NotSupportedException " and most importantly "The explicit construction of the entity in a query is invalid.", others will be able to more easily find your question and the answer.